# Adding string to a string before some certain characters?

Tags: python

```
myString = '(247, 246, 244), (13, 23, 24), (85, 101, 100)'

substring = 'rgb'
```

- I want to add this string the substring above, before every '(' character. So that it would be look like this below.

  myString = 'rgb(247, 246, 244), rgb(13, 23, 24), rgb(85, 101, 100)'

Comment: `mystring.replace("(", "rgb(")` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `.replace()` method, ie `myString.replace("(", "rgb(")` this will just go through the string and replace every `"("` with `"rgb("`.

Answer (score 0):

Just showing full implementation of Jasonharper's, where you change how you define your sub-string and replace the opening parenthesis:

```
myString = '(247, 246, 244), (13, 23, 24), (85, 101, 100)'
substring = 'rgb('
myString.replace("(", substring)
```